# Sort List Object based on Unique key using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I need to sort similar record which have all details similar except for id into one record and not change the other record.Below is the example

```
INPUT                               
Id  First Name  Last Name   Mobile  Email
1   John    B   9000000000  john@gmail.com
2   John    B   9000000000  john@gmail.com
3   Swamy   P   9999999999  abc@gmail.com
4   kelvin  F   8888888888  def@gmail.com

OUTPUT              
Id  First Name  Last Name   Mobile  Email
1|2 John    B   9000000000  john@gmail.com
3   Swamy   P   9999999999  abc@gmail.com
4   kelvin  F   8888888888  def@gmail.com
```

As per the above example similar records are merged into one except for the unique key which has all the similar unique ids seperated by pipe symbol.

Comment: Why don't you use `.OrderByDescending`?

Comment: This is not a question. If you don't show what you tried, we don't know where you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Mobile, x.Email })
                 .Select(x => new 
                                 {
                                    Id = String.Join("|",x.Select(z => z.Id)),
                                    FirstName = x.Key.FirstName
                                    LastName = x.Key.LastName,
                                    Mobile = x.Key.Mobile,
                                    Email = x.Key.Email
                                 });
```